# Multiplexing problem with Arduino, MAX7219 e BJT

Tags: arduino, led, transistors, bjt, multiplexer

I tested the circuit below with an Arduino UNO, a MAX7219 and BC338. The sketch in Arduino is a chaser, so the leds should turn on in sequence. It consist of 7 segment (A-G) and two Digit (0-1).

The problem is that when one segment is turned on (and only that led sould be), also the same segment on the other digit is turned on. The problem si showed in the image below.

I tried with pull-up resistor and other tests, but I don't know what's the problem. Thank you for your help.

[image: My Circuit]

[image: Photo of the problem]

Answer (score 1):

Brhans is right you can't put NPN transistors there you either need a pullup resistor or PNP there but i fail to see the point since inside max u already have a NPN transistor driving that line. I think you will have better luck if you explain what you are trying to accomplish, im guessing some weird dimming or something similar witch wont work anyway. Have in mind that 7219 uses multiplexing as a means to drive more than 8 leds.

Comment: [THIS](http://embedded-lab.com/blog/?p=7628) project is very similar to my final one, I have ULN2003 instead of ULN2803 and 74LS04 instead of 74HC540. The problem is the same also with all the parts so I reduce the circuit with only two NPN to solve the problem.

Comment: this morning I've tried the same circuit explained in the link of my previous comment, with the same components. The result is the same, same problem.

Comment: ULN2803 and 2003 are basically the same just 1 extra darlington pair on 2803 good for dot on 7 segment display. In the circuit you provided its meant to sink current.But as for 74LS04 that is TTL IC and 74HC540 is CMOS im guessing you have a conflict there. Im 2 busy to analyze their datasheets.You can write what parts you have available i can make modifications for your schematic.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those transistors in your circuit. 
The DIG outputs of the MAX7219 are designed to sink current directly from the common point of your LEDs.
If for some reason you really think you need transistors in there, then use PNPs instead of the NPNs you have.

Comment: Without transistors it works perfectly, but I need them for the second step of my tests.

Comment: Then use PNP BC328 transistors instead. Emitters go up to your LED commons, collectors to GND.